# How can I force QueryFullProcessImageNameW to give me the full form?

Tags: winapi

I'm enumerating the running processes, and for each process, using `QueryFullProcessImageNameW` to get the path on disk of the process.

`QueryFullProcessImageNameW` returns a path like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\ALongFolderName\foobar.exe"` for most processes.

But for some processes, I get the old 8.3 format instead, like `"C:\PROGRA~2\ALONGF~1\foobar.exe'"`

How can I always retrieve the long form, as I can see it in File Explorer?

Comment: @AlexK. At run time i don't know if QueryFullProcessImageNameW returned a short name or long name. Is it safe to pass either into GetLongPathName?

Comment: @SteveMcLeod The docs don't say that the name must be a short name. So I'ld give it a try. BTW, `GetShortPathName` explicitely allows to pass a short path name - whatever that might mean for `GetLongPathName`.

Comment: From the Remarks section, it seems like calling GetLongPathName on a long name should return a copy of the long name, so I'd expect it to be safe to always call it.  But I'd test to be sure.

Comment: @AlexK your solution seems to work. If the GetLongPathName returns 0 then it seems I already have the long path. If it returns  > 0, then it gives me the long path. Care to create an answer so I can accept it as the correct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot force the API to return the long form; it simply returns the path that was used to load the corresponding image in the first place.

You can instead call [`GetLongPathName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364980(v=vs.85).aspx) to translate an 8.3 name into its long form.